# Как обработать сбой обмена TCP сообщений?

Tags: delphi, сеть, tcp

Клиент (port 51694 ) с сервером (port 9999) обмениваются сообщениями по TCP, посылается сообщение типа **[PSH, ACK]** и **[ACK]**.

В какой то момент не приходит ответ на "Главный" запрос клиента и он висит в ожидании, при этом продолжает пинговать, если выйти в меню, а потом вернуться в игру, можно продолжать

Лог в момент ошибки из WireShark

```
   Главный запрос клиента 
338    51694 → opsmessaging(8090) [PSH, ACK] Seq=30071 Ack=185415 Win=65944 Len=284
54     opsmessaging(8090) → 51694 [ACK] Seq=185415 Ack=30355 Win=64768 Len=0
   Главный ответ 1 сервера
578    opsmessaging(8090) → 51694 [PSH, ACK] Seq=185415 Ack=30355 Win=64768 Len=524
54     51694 → opsmessaging(8090) [ACK] Seq=30355 Ack=185939 Win=65420 Len=0
   Главный ответ 2 сервера
1265   opsmessaging(8090) → 51694 [PSH, ACK] Seq=185939 Ack=30355 Win=64768 Len=1211
54     51694 → opsmessaging(8090) [ACK] Seq=30355 Ack=187150 Win=66240 Len=0
   Главный запрос клиента
338    51694 → opsmessaging(8090) [PSH, ACK] Seq=30355 Ack=187150 Win=66240 Len=284
54     opsmessaging(8090) → 51694 [ACK] Seq=187150 Ack=30639 Win=66048 Len=0
   Главный ответ 1 сервера
810    opsmessaging(8090) → 51694 [PSH, ACK] Seq=187150 Ack=30639 Win=66048 Len=756
54     51694 → opsmessaging(8090) [ACK] Seq=30639 Ack=187906 Win=65484 Len=0
   Главный ответ 2 сервера
1265   opsmessaging(8090) → 51694 [PSH, ACK] Seq=187906 Ack=30639 Win=66048 Len=1211
54     51694 → opsmessaging(8090) [ACK] Seq=30639 Ack=189117 Win=66240 Len=0
   Вторичный запрос клиента
296    51694 → opsmessaging(8090) [PSH, ACK] Seq=30639 Ack=189117 Win=66240 Len=242
54     opsmessaging(8090) → 51694 [ACK] Seq=189117 Ack=30881 Win=65792 Len=0
   Ping запрос клиента
212    51694 → opsmessaging(8090) [PSH, ACK] Seq=30881 Ack=189117 Win=66240 Len=158
   Вторичный ответ сервера
415    opsmessaging(8090) → 51694 [PSH, ACK] Seq=189117 Ack=30881 Win=65792 Len=361
   Главный запрос клиента
338    51694 → opsmessaging(8090) [PSH, ACK] Seq=31039 Ack=189478 Win=65876 Len=284
54     opsmessaging(8090) → 51694 [ACK] Seq=189478 Ack=31323 Win=65536 Len=0
   Ping ответ 1 сервера
278    opsmessaging(8090) → 51694 [PSH, ACK] Seq=189478 Ack=31323 Win=65536 Len=224
54     51694 → opsmessaging(8090) [ACK] Seq=31323 Ack=189702 Win=65652 Len=0
   Ping ответ 2 сервера
1265   opsmessaging(8090) → 51694 [PSH, ACK] Seq=189702 Ack=31323 Win=65536 Len=1211
54     51694 → opsmessaging(8090) [ACK] Seq=31323 Ack=190913 Win=66240 Len=0
Дальше Ping запрос/ответ 1/ответ 2 повторяются
```

Я пишу серверную часть, на Delphi, клиент flash игра. Я хочу понять, причину, почему это происходит?

Как, такую ошибку можно обработать, что б все работало дальше? На сервере ошибок нет, хотя запущен он в режиме debugg.

**UPD**

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  ReqStrem : TMemoryStream;
  ReqData  : TIdBytes;
  ReqString : String;
  ResString: ZResString;
begin
//
  if AContext.Connection.Connected then
  begin
    try
      if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size > 0 then
      begin
// начало чтения из потока
        ReqStrem := TMemoryStream.Create;
        AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(ReqStrem,
          AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size, false);
        ReqStrem.Position := 0;
        ReadTIdBytesFromStream(ReqStrem, ReqData, ReqStrem.Size);
        ReqStrem.Free;
        ReqString := BytesToString(ReqData, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
// конец чтения из потока
        ResString := RGetTCPRespons.TcpResCreate(ReqString);
  // Главный/Ping ответ 1 сервера, Вторичный
          AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferOpen;
          AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(ResString.xText + #0);
          AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferFlush;
          AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferClear;
          AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferClose;
  // Главный/Ping  ответ 2 сервера
        if ResString.JPText <> '' then
        begin
          AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferOpen;
          AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(ResString.jpText + #0);
          AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferFlush;
          AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferClear;
          AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferClose;
        end;
    finally
    sleep(100);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

**UPD2**

Как мне правильно организовать чтение, что бы по отдельности обрабатывать сообщения, если они заканчиваются на #0.

Comment: Должна быть такая строчка {54     opsmessaging(8090) → 51694 [ACK] Seq=189117 Ack=31039 Win=????? Len=0} Но как вычислять ее программно, как понять когда она не посылалась или не дошла до клиента

Comment: Пересчитал заново Seq и Ack, вроде все верно оказалось,  тогда в чем проблема!?

Comment: Самое простое - выставить тайм-ауты - тогда, если клиент что-то отправил и не получил ответный ACK, то read на клиенте вылетит с Exception и он сможет заново подключиться. Аналогично с другой стороны.

Comment: не помогло, клиент сторонний, то что в настройках есть попробовал, а код я не могу изменить, есть еще предложения?

Comment: Ack и Seq те что приходят на сервер, если не было принято сообщение будут приходить  меньше чем должны? Тогда можно на 3-4 pinge если суммы не соответствуют отправить сообщение еще раз? Мысль верная? Если да подскажите как реализовать

Comment: Как программно проверить эти суммы, и при повторе сообщения выровнять их

Comment: Представьте, что получится, если в `ReqStrem` окажется не одна, а сразу 2 команды от клиента (или полторы, или 0,5)? При работе по TCP в сети (не на локальном компьютере) это более чем возможно.

Comment: Я понял, а как мне с этим бороться, даже так, что мне в поисковик вбить чтоб найти  нужный материал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Читаю так, до нулевого бита, ошибка больше не появляется

ReqString := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn(#0);

Comment: Как всегда, сбой не в TCP, а в понимании этого протокола.