# Как получить Ack и Seq суммы TCP пакета в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, tcp

Я использую IdTcpServer, как мне на сервере получить контрольную сумму Ack и Seq, от сообщения что прислал клиент? Например IP клиента хранится в PeerIP, а где эти переменные?

Comment: Я боюсь они на прикладном уровне вообще не доступны, так как никому там не нужны. На прикладном уровне сокета TCP даже понятия "пакет" не существует. Интересно, зачем они понадобились вам

Comment: Идет обмен сообщениями, мой сервер и сторонний клиент, иногда клиент висит в ожидании ответа, но при этом связь не обрывается и клиент продолжает слать пинг сообщения, я хочу посмотреть сумму в пинг сообщении, если она не увеличилась на сумму последнего сообщения, послать его еще раз

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/668659/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-tcp-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9

Comment: ACK и SEQ - это флаги. Если хотите - можете найти их бинарные значения, нагуглить любую утилиту вроде "crc32 онлайн" и вручную посчитать контрольную сумму. Что именно вы хотите - неясно, и вряд ли кто-то будет разбираться в смутном описании и простыне кода. Создайте новый проект клиента и проект сервера, напишите минималистичный код, демонстрирующий проблему (и если религия позволяет - лучше сделать это на C# или хотя бы WinAPI, чем Indy), и задайте новый вопрос - и скорее всего (но не факт) задача будет решаемой без низкоуровневой эзотерики, и, вероятно (но совсем не факт) вам ответят

Comment: Я сейчас еще раз все перепроверяю, но вроде у меня сервер посылает сообщение, а до клиента оно не доходит, я пытаюсь это исправить. C# и WinAPI увы не знаю

Comment: не приходит не первое сообщение, идет диалог, сбой может быть на 1000 сообщении а может на 100

Comment: TCP - протокол потоковый, фрагментируемый. Возможно, ваш сервер неправильно обрабатывает (или вообще не обрабатывает) разбиение и склейку пакетов. Без кода что-либо сказать сложно.

Comment: @ArtGrek13 прочитал переписку под тем вопросом ... Так вот, за обработку флагов TCP и повторную передачу, если это необходимо отвечает ОС. С точки зрения приложения никаких повторов или недошедших данных (кроме ситуации обрыва коннекта) быть не может. Зато ОС имеет полное право отдать приложению за одно Read например половину пришедшего пакета, а вторую половину отдать позже. или наоборот несколько пакетов склеить и приложение получит все данные в одном Read.

Comment: Поэтому приложение должно само контролировать длину данных, и если протокол с #0 на конце "пакетов", то приложение само должно читать понемногу входящий поток и искать там #0 и как нашло обрабатывать, а если не нашло, то читать продолжение пока оно не придет. Я пока не в курсе как работает Indy, делает ли он это сам. Но если вдруг он сам не рассчитан на анализ #0 в конце сообщения, то делать это должны вы. А вот "опускаться" (по уровням OSI) на такой низкий уровень как обработка информации заголовков TCP не следует. это вам ничего не даст.

Comment: И для отладки надо не морочить себе голову WireShark и его выдачей, а расставлять в приложении отладочную печать длины прочитанных данных и их дампов, что бы понять где происходит сдвижка. То что показывает WireShark это совершенно не то, что отдает вам Indy. P.S. И sleep() делать в циклах чтения не принято. Если надо спать, спите прямо на приемном сокете, т.е. до получения данных

Comment: Кстати ... если за время вашего `sleep(100)` прийдет более одного "пакета" по соединению, то очень высока вероятность, что InputBuffer.Size будет уже суммой их длины и вы за одно чтение прочтете оба пакета и обработаете как один ...

Comment: я еще не знаю как, но допустим пришло мне полтора сообщения, я прочел до #0, ответил, когда я буду читать в следующий раз, я увижу только вторую половину второго сообщения?